# Adding a column with logarithm in Dataframe Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, logarithm

I have a dataframe in which I'm trying to add a column which will basically be taking the logarithm of an existing column in the same dataframe. I am trying this :

```
    df = df.withColumn("logvalue", log(df["prediction_column"]) )
```

I have already checked the schema of the dataframe and the prediction column is float type. But I keep getting the error that 
  **TypeError: a float is required**

What am I missing here ? Any suggestions will be of great help

Comment: try `log("prediction_column")` just the column name

Comment: You're using the wrong `log` function- my guess is you're trying `numpy.log` or `math.log`. Try adding `from pyspark.sql.functions import log` (this will be natural log).

Comment: any idea why `np.log` does not work? I was not able to figure out this...

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following, it worked for me

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df = df.withColumn("logvalue", log10(col("prediction_column"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try to use the column name without the dataframe or you can use the function `col` but here you have to import `from pyspark.sql.functions import col` and then `log(col("double_col"))`:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
(1.3 ,"s"),
(10.3 ,"t"),
(3.3 ,"x"),
(1.5 ,"u"),
(1.3 ,"v")
], ("double_col", "char"))

print df.schema
print df.withColumn("bla", log("double_col")).show()
```

Output:

```
StructType(List(StructField(double_col,DoubleType,true),StructField(char,StringType,true)))
+----------+----+-------------------+
|double_col|char|                bla|
+----------+----+-------------------+
|       1.3|   s|0.26236426446749106|
|      10.3|   t|   2.33214389523559|
|       3.3|   x| 1.1939224684724346|
|       1.5|   u| 0.4054651081081644|
|       1.3|   v|0.26236426446749106|
+----------+----+-------------------+
```